# Wrong output with logcat inside my application

Tags: android, logcat

I'm developing a multi-tab application. In one of the tab I want to show the logcat but I have a lot of problem running it correctly.

Right now I'm using the following command but I don't get anything in my TextView. :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/logcat -s com.vittorio:I");
```

But when I run the same command into Terminal it works flawlessy.

I've also tryed this other command :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/logcat *:I");
```

but for some reason it prints also Debug level messages ...

EDIT (1):

I've by-passed the problem by adding an high-level filter (java) to the whole log.. so I only print in my textview what I need. It's a very dirty solution but for now is the only one I managed to come with.

I would like to point out that I'me experiencing different behaviours on my phones :

- Galaxy S Plus (rooted) : I can see the log.
- Galaxy Y (rooted) : No log
- Nexus One (not-rooted) : No log

EDIT (2) - **SOLVED (NEED ROOTED PHONE)**:

After some struggling I managed to solve my problem. Actually navigating through the init.rc system file I saw that the permissions for /dev/log/main and /dev/log/system where setted to 620.. that's why I couldn't open the log on some of my phones. So I rooted also my Nexus One and added this commands into my activity before calling the logcat command :

```
Process process_su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Process process_ch = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /dev/log/main");
```

Done! :D

Hope this info will help anyone who will face my same issue.

Comment: logcat is not supposed to work from an application. I think there is a permission, but I don't think it is officially supported

Comment: Actually there are a lot of application that print the logcat, so I think this is not the real issue :). And anyway I'm able to print the whole log but I't useless if I can't filter what I want to see! :D

Comment: did you try to split the arguments into a String[] ? ([0] is the command [1-n] are the arguments)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

and then you can use that snippet i found

```
    try {
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v");

      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

      StringBuilder logString=new StringBuilder();
      String line;

      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        logString.append(line);
      }

      TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logTextView);
      tv.setText(logString.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

I didn't try it but it seems correct

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've already the permission in my manifest and actually my code is very similar to the one you posted. Anyway I've by-passed the problem by adding an high-level filter (java) to the whole log.. so I only print in my textview what I need. It's a very dirty solution but for now is the only one i managed to come with

Comment: It may have something to do with the logcat parameters, have you tried with -d?

Comment: yeah I've tryed a lot of different parameters combinations but without success :(

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this code it seems to do the same thing as you but maybe there are some small differences http://code.google.com/p/android-random/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FLogcat%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fdevtcg%2Ftools%2Flogcat